# Drag text on PaperJS canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, drag, droppable, paperjs

I'm trying to drag a  containing some text to a Canvas which is controlled by PaperJs. Using Jquery "droppable" I can drop some text into the canvas through paperjs, but I cannot get the coördinates/position of the drop right. Can anyone help?

```
$("#canvasVertical").droppable({
      drop: function (event, ui) {
          var text = new paper.PointText(new Point(??, ??));
          text.justification = 'center';
          text.fontSize = 12;
          text.fontcolor = "blue";
          text.content = "text form the div or span";
      }
 });
```

I've tried to get the position of the drop using event.target or event or ui, but cannot get it right so the dropped text is rendered at the position of the mouse.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a straightforward way for jQuery or your code to know exactly the right point to use to achieve your desired end result. The first problem you run into is that paper's coordinates are relative to the top left of the canvas while jQuery's mouse positions vary from that - the closest is probably `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`, but that includes any padding around the canvas, so take all that into account. If you make sure that the canvas has no padding then `event.offset?` should be correct for your canvas.

Once you've adjusted the event point to canvas coordinates for paper, you could duplicate the logic paper uses or you can just let paper do it's work and then adjust the position of the `PointText` so it is where you want it.

I would take the second approach - it's a bit confusing because the point you supply when creating a `PointText`, while used for the x-axis starting point of the text, is not used for the starting point on the y-axis (not `topLeft`, `bottomLeft` or even `centerY` of the bounding rectangle).

`text.position` is the center of `text.bounds`, the bounding rectangle.

The most straightforward process I can think of is to:

1. Create `text` using `paper.PointText`
2. set the content of `text`
3. use `text.bounds` or `text.position` to readjust the position

For example, if you want the center of the text to be positioned at the drop point:

```
$("#canvasVertical").droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
      // may need to convert event.offsetX, event.offsetY coordinates
      // to canvas coordinates.
      var pos = new paper.Point(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      // pos could really be anything here
      var text = new paper.PointText(pos);
      text.justification = 'center';
      text.fontSize = 12;
      text.fontcolor = "blue";
      text.content = "text form the div or span";
      // now use the adjusted drop point to set the center position
      // of text.
      text.position = pos;
  }
})
```

It's a similar process if you want the drop point to be the `topLeft`, `bottomLeft` or `centerY` of the text's bounding rectangle. You will have to calculate the difference between the desired location (drop point) and the rendered location then use that offset to adjust the position, e.g.,

```
// this replaces the text.position = pos line above
// and assumes that the drop point should be the bottomLeft
// position of text.
var delta = text.bounds.bottomLeft.subtract(pos);
text.position = text.position.add(delta);
```

To adjust it to `topLeft` is almost the same. To adjust `centerY` is slightly more work because `centerY` doesn't include the leftmost X value which must come separately from `text.bounds`.